# How to concatenate fasta files with identical names into one file with different headers?

Tags: bash, fasta, consensus

My problem is more on how to rename the header line for each fasta sequence, as I know how to concatenate a bunch of fasta files into one file. The problem is, after generating my files each file has the exact same header (name of the gene that was analyzed). So what I want to do is just combine the sequences but instead of keeping the same header, I want to use the filename as the header.

Example, I have two fasta files, the first being:

```
Homo_sapien_XYZ_20102.fa
```

And inside this file the sequence is:

```
>gene_X
ACTGAGGCCAATGAA...
```

Then a second file called:

```
Homo_sapein_ABC_20102.fa

>gene_X
CCCTGAGTAGAT...
```

When I concatenate these files I end up with one new file that has different sequences but identical headers (and due to the nature of the scripts I use to generate these individual sequences I cannot change the header name prior to this step).

```
>gene_X
ACTGAGGCCAATGAA...
>gene_X
CCCTGAGTAGAT...
```

This will be problematic so I was hoping to rewrite that header using the filename so it ends up being:

```
>Homo_sapien_XYZ_20102
ACTGAGGCCAATGAA...
>Homo_sapein_ABC_20102
CCCTGAGTAGAT...
```

Anyone know how to do this? The line of code I used to create one file of sequences is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

for files in *_20102.fa
do
    cat ${files} >> geneA_consensus.fa
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with my test set.

```
for file in *.fasta
do
   echo ">$file" >> out.fasta
   tail -n +2 $file >> out.fasta
   echo >> out.fasta
done
```

This simple version includes the filename extension.

That last echo ensures the next header appears on its own line, even if the prior FASTA file did not end in a newline.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print ">" FILENAME; next}1' *_20102.fa > geneA_consensus.fa
```

no loops needed.

Comment: Didn't work it made everything on one line and either merged or overwritten by the last file few files.

Comment: your line endings might be `\r\n` if it's coming from windows.  you can fix them by running `dos2unix` on files.  Or, add `-v RS='\r?\n'` option.

Comment: I'm using bash on windows, writing the scripts in nano because I always ran into those line ending problems before. But I got it to work now :)

Comment: This did not work for me. This does not provide the > at the start of the (new filename headers to make it a valid .fasta file.